# Component is updating when previous props are equal to the next props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In simple todo list application, I have `FiltersContainer` component, which provides props to `Filters` component:

```js
// FiltersContainer.js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setVisibilityFilter } from '../actions';
import Filters from '../components/Filters';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { visibilityFilter } = state.todos;

  // `visibilityFilter` variable value is - 'SHOW_ALL'.
  return {
    filters: [{
      title: 'All',
      value: 'SHOW_ALL',
      active: visibilityFilter === 'SHOW_ALL',
    }, {
      title: 'Completed',
      value: 'SHOW_COMPLETED',
      active: visibilityFilter === 'SHOW_COMPLETED',
    }, {
      title: 'Active',
      value: 'SHOW_ACTIVE',
      active: visibilityFilter === 'SHOW_ACTIVE',
    }],
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onFilterClick(value) {
      dispatch(setVisibilityFilter(value));
    },
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Filters);
```

The problem is, that this component renders everytime state changes.
For example, toggling todo item forces rendering `<Filters />` component, although `filters` array and `visibilityFilter` hasn't changed.

---

If replace `filters` array in `mapStateToProps` function with string, this component would not be rendering on every state changes:

```js
// FiltersContainer.js
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { visibilityFilter } = state.todos;

  return {
    filters: '',
  };
}
```

Full application code is available at - https://github.com/1ven/react-redux-todos

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `shallowEqual` util function, which uses `react-redux` library to check whether component props changed.

This function does not makes `deepEqual` checking, it only makes `shallow` checking, thats why object, which contains property with array is not equal to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

EveryTime you are returning a new Object from mapStateToProps thats why old props are not equal to the new props.
Hence the component gets rendered everytime

React render the component if old props are not equal to new props
In your case you do

```
 return {
    filters: [{
      title: 'All',
      value: 'SHOW_ALL',
      active: visibilityFilter === 'SHOW_ALL',
    }, {
      title: 'Completed',
      value: 'SHOW_COMPLETED',
      active: visibilityFilter === 'SHOW_COMPLETED',
    }, {
      title: 'Active',
      value: 'SHOW_ACTIVE',
      active: visibilityFilter === 'SHOW_ACTIVE',
    }],
  };
```

oldProps = object

newProps = another object (although content is same both are different objects )

oldprops==newprops //no rerender

When you do

```
return {
    filters: '',
  };
```

oldprops = '';
newprops = ''
 oldprops === newprops dont render

Comment: No, when I'm returning `{ filters: '' }` object from `mapStateToProps`, `<Filters />` component is not rerendering everytime, although this function always returns new object.

Comment: Thanks for updating answer, but this question is rather related to `react-redux` library then to `react` itself. In react, if not to define `shouldComponentUpdate` function, component will be rendering everytime it parent component rerenders. The problem is solved, it was related to `shallowEqual` function from `react-redux` library.